# Is it Efficient?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have data Json in aray. and I de-serialize in ajax.
I want to change the class from element if it has class 'Booked'. is it efficient to write like this ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "URL.aspx/GetData",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function (response) {            
        var arr = JSON.parse(response.d);           
        objData = new Array();
        objData = arr;
        for (i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {

            if (jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).hasClass('seat-booked'))
            {
                jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).addClass('seat-availiable');                    
                jQuery('#class-' + objData[i].noSeat).attr('value', 'seat-availiable');
                jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).removeClass('seat-booked');
                jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).removeClass('selected');
            }                
        }
```

I put

> `if`

statement in

> `for`

looping. I want to make it faster to processed. is it the best way ?

Comment: First point of optimization would be to put `jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat)` in a variable.

Comment: I think it woulb be the same as my way. it's just shorten the code not the process

Comment: It would save you the time taken by jQuery to search for the element every time you do `jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat)`.

Comment: You also might want to chain them - .addClass().removeClass() - no performance gain though if you already are using a variable. Also better to do a removeClass('seat-booked selected')

Comment: This question belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since there is no specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try for I in

```
for (var I in objData) {
  objData[I] // stuff
}
```

Edit: fixing my mistake, if only phones had autocorrect. 
I only meant that I think for-in loops are better than for i = 0; i < length; i++ style loops.

To make it up i'll try suggesting this untested code and downvote me if it fails :)

```
for (i in objData) {
    jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat + '.seat-booked')
        .addClass('seat-availiable')
        .removeClass('seat-booked selected')
        .closest('#class-' + objData[i].noSeat)
        .val('seat-availiable');
}
```

for-in looks at each element in the objData and is similar to the i=0; i<l; i++; but seems like it makes fewer assignments.
the Jquery('selector') can take multiple conditions and if there's no space between the ID and the class like '#' + objData[i].noSeat + '.seat-booked', it needs both to return the object. Then all the add/remove stuff can be added to the returned object. If there's no object returned nothing else in the chain can execute, so nothing happens.

Comment: sorry I dint get your answer can you please explain it further

Comment: what about the condition ?

Comment: Sorry about that what I meant to post before was that the for-in loop I think is somewhat less overhead than the `for (i=0;i<length;i++)` part, not sure what I was smoking with the if part.... Sorry about that.